# JS Custom Event Triggered 2 Time

Tags: javascript, angular, custom-events

I'm going crazy trying to figure out what the heck is going on. In practice I have an angular v9 app that uses a shared.js file where I have stored some functions that I share with part of the static frontend. At some point from the angular app I start the call to the addToCart () function. This function among many actions has the task of emitting the onAddToCart event to do other UI update stuff. I have other similar calls (ex. Login) and they work fine, this one doesn't.

```
ANGULAR COMPONENT HTML
<button (click)="addProductToCart(product)">Add</button>

ANGULAR COMPONENT TS
declare function addToCart(request): any;
-----
addProductToCart(product: Product): void {
  addToCart(product);
}

SHARED.JS
function addToCart(product) {
...
dispatchEventAddToCart(cartItem);
}

function dispatchEventAddToCart(cartItem) {
  const addToCart = new CustomEvent('onAddToCart', {
    detail: cartItem
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(addToCart);
}
```

```
(() => {
  refreshCartCounter();
  window.addEventListener('onAddToCart', (e) => {
    refreshCartCounter();
    console.log('add to cart executed'); <= I see two log always!
  });
})();
```

```
ANGULAR COMPONENT TEMPLATE
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
              <tr>
              <th scope="col">Prodotto</th>
              <th scope="col">SKU</th>
              <th scope="col">Descrizione</th>
              <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
              <th scope="col">Marca</th>
              <th scope="col">Preventivo</th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody *ngIf="productFindResponse">
            <tr *ngFor="let product of productFindResponse.products">
              <td>
                <figure class="media">
                   <img src="{{ product.image}}" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-sm" #img (error)="img.src = getDefaultImage()" alt="{{ product.sku }} - {{ product.description }}">
                </figure>
                </td>
                <td><a href="{{ product.skuNorm }}">{{ product.sku }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.category.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.brand.name }}</td>
                <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addProductToCart(product)"> Add <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                </button>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Im tried to set bubble = false but the result is the same..

Comment: There is just not enough information here to determine where the duplication comes from. Just console the hell out out of it I guess? Does your addProductToCart get called twice..? Does your addToCart get triggered twice?

Comment: I see the log more time (2) - console.log('add to cart executed'); - 
Ive debugged more time but the call is only one, it seems the problem is the listener!

Comment: hell!! the problem is the (click)="addProductToCart(product)" of Angular component. I'v call the js function by ngOnInit(){addToCart()} and trigger one time only... suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the template?

Comment: sure, ive posted.. thank for interest! i tried to call by a simple link or button outside the *ngfor but the result is same. Double event emitted.. i dont known..

Comment: Hmm.. nothing strange there..sorry man.. no idea..

Comment: any solution for this :) ? I have the same problem in clean JS :)

Comment: HI. My problem was the listener, basically when the event was executed it triggers the dispatch once again. I solved it by adding a traffic light to the event. I hope this can help you. If you like, vote for my speech and current post :)